# REST URLs: integer vs string and the behavior of PUT

Tags: json, api, rest

This is a multi-part question:

1. Given a REST API with URLs containing natural numbers as path segments, is the generally expected behavior that the number be interpreted as an index or a key?
2. When performing a **PUT** against a deep resource path, is the generally expected behavior that the path be interpreted as a declaration of state? Meaning that all non-existent resources along the path be created. Or should an error be returned if any resource along the path does not exist?
3. Expanding on question 2, if the path does exist, and the path defines a resource structure differing from that which is present, should the preexisting resources be overwritten, again as a declaration of state, or should an error be returned indicating a type mismatch?

For example, consider the endpoint:

`domain.tld/datasource/foo/2/bar/1/baz`

- `foo` is a string, and identifies a top level resource.
- `2` could be interpreted as either an index or a key.
- `bar` is a string, interpreted as a key.
- `1` could be interpreted as either an index or a key.
- `baz` is a string, interpreted as a key, pointing to a leaf node.

In other words, the data residing at `domain.tld/datasource` under the identifier `foo` could be any of the following:

index based:

```
[
  null,
  null,
  {
    'bar': [
      null,
      {'baz': null}
    ]
  }
]
```

key based:

```
{
  '2': {
    'bar': {
      '1': {
        {'baz': null}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

both index and key based:

```
{
  '2': {
    'bar': [
      null,
      {'baz': null}
    ]
  }
}
```

**Question 1**

Should `2` and `1` be considered an integer or a string? As this is potentially impossible to know, is there a standard for type annotation in REST URLs for addressing this case? Some solutions on the whiteboard so far are as follows with the assertion that `2` is a key and `1` is an index:

- `domain.tld/datasource/foo/2:str/bar/1:int/baz`

  - where `:str` indicates that the preceding value is a key
  - and `:int` indicates that the preceding value is an index
- `domain.tld/datasource/foo/2/bar/1/baz?types=ki`

  - where `k`, being member 0 of `types`, maps to the first int-like segment, and indicates that the value is a key
  - and `i`, being member 1 of `types`, maps to the second int-like segment, and indicates that the value is an index

**Question 2**

If none of the above data was present, should a **PUT** against this path create those resources or return an error? If an error is returned, should each resource at each level be created individually, requiring multiple **PUT**s against the path?

**Question 3**

If the data from the first illustration (index based) is already present should the data from the second illustration (key based) forcibly overwrite all data at all levels in the path or return an error indicating a type mismatch? The inference here being that again, multiple **PUT**s are required for any assignment that changes the type.

I'm probably over-complicating the issue or missing something basic but I haven't found much in the way of definitive guidance. I have complete control over the system and can enforce any rules I see fit. However, I'm interested in the experience, meaning interactions should be easy to reason about, logical, expected, deterministic, etc.

Comment: Regarding the last 2 questions, I think it depends on what level in your RESTful API at. For example, looking at [level 3 of the Richardson Maturity Model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html#level3), you'd have to actually navigate to a resource before executing a PUT against it, so you can assume that the path is valid. At the same time, hardcoding urls instead of navigating is not the proper way to consume such an API.

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, you should never ever make something like 'deep resources' when trying to be 'restful' or 'resty' - i really don't see the benefit. It just makes the system way harder to understand, to use and to develop (eg.: see your questions :) ).

Why not keep it simple and having 'single' URLs for single resources? That way it is clear to the client what a PUT will do, what a DELETE will do.

So just as an example, you could have the list resource endpoint domain.com/datasource which will return a list of all foos registered. It will return a list of HREFs...like domain.com/foo/1 ... beneath some metadata, foo/1 could also include a list of bars....but again, they are not nested in the 'foo URI', they are simple top level resources eg 'domain.com/bar/1'.

This way a client can easily delete, update, create items. You can link them, bu setting the correct links in the entities.

Regarding your question 2 and 3: I think that totally depends on your system. If you see the link domain.com/datasource/foo/1/bar/2/baz as ONE big resource, meaning the response will not only include information about baz, but also of bar, foo and datasource, yes a put would 'recreate' (full update) the resource. If that link "only" returns information about baz, a put would only full update this resource.